# How to use Unite.vim history yank

Tags: vim

According to [the Unite.vim doc](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/master/doc/unite.txt), I added the followings to my .vimrc.

```
let g:unite_source_history_yank_enable = 1
nnoremap <leader>y :<C-u>Unite history/yank<CR>
```

But I am not suer how to use this. I yanked some lines and typed `\y` but it shows nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was forking from an (old) configuration, tried exact same thing and came across your question. Maybe it has changed since when you post it, now it seems cited under external sources in [unite.txt](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/master/doc/unite.txt)

```
history/yank source:
https://github.com/Shougo/neoyank.vim
```